# Do I need MySQL commercial License for my mobile App selled to users?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a multi platform application and want to use MySQL as the database behind. I read about GPL License. The license wants me to publish my source code, if I use the free version of MySQL. I dont want to publish my source code.

So is it allowed to use MySQL as the database and build for example an mobile App with Android, that uses the data from there, without publishing my Android source code?

Thank you

Comment: If you bundle the database with your application, then yes you must purchase a commercial license. If your app only accesses a server that is not part of your distribution then it might be that you don't need one. As an alternative you could use a DBMS that is "really" free and will never require a license like Firebird or Postgres (they don't have a GPL license but a BSD style one). But: **I am not a lawyer**, if you need to be sure, contact one!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to bundle MySQL with your Android; You probably host your MySQL along with your web server, isn't it?

So, the answer is No, you don't need commercial license for your App.

Answer (score 0):

At first please have a look at the MySQL [licensing page](http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html) what model really applies to your software.

I think as long as you only want to connect to a MySQL database you somehow can do what you want (but don't bundle the client libraries). The rule of thumb is don't include/bundle anything from Oracle/MySQL and you are on the good side.

It is ok if the *user* downloads and installs the MySQL-package, but it is *not you* who delivers it with your software (which would be bundling again).
I think it is also ok to write a script which automatically downloads and installs it from the Oracle pages (note - there are better ways: e.g. dpkg), but I'm not a licensing expert.

The [GPL FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html) might help you to get a sense for using and publishing GPLed software.
An [overview/comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_software_licenses) of free and open-source software licenses can be found at Wikipedia.

Hope that helped a bit.

*Jost